# Titanium : How to load an external custom AlertDialog in Alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I code all my project in Alloy, so no classic Titanium here.
I want to load an external custom AlertDialog (located in views/popup.xml) in my index. So my need is to show an alert and destroy it (for ie.) by clicking the OK button. The Help button should do another action.

My popup.xml file :

```
<Alloy>
    <AlertDialog id="popup" title="Error popup"
        message="There is an error" cancel="1">
        <ButtonNames>
            <ButtonName>OK</ButtonName>
            <ButtonName>Help</ButtonName>
        </ButtonNames>
    </AlertDialog>
</Alloy>
```

My index.js file :

```
function openPopup(e) {
    var page = Alloy.createController('views/popup').getView();
    page.show();
};
openPopup();
```

But this gives me an error :

- [DEBUG] [iphone, 8.1, 192.168.0.1] Native
  module:alloy/controllers/views/popup
- [ERROR] [iphone, 8.1, 192.168.0.1] Couldn't find module:
  alloy/controllers/views/popup
- [ERROR] [iphone, 8.1, 192.168.0.1] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a
  constructor (evaluating 'new (__p.require("alloy/controllers/" +
  name))(args)')

I have no popup.js and I didn't require any file in index.js too. So my questions are : How to load a controller dynamically? How to remove (or destroy) it with an addEventListener on "click" action? Thank you.

Comment: only use `Alloy.createController('popup').getView();`, not `views/popup`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with turtle. When you create a controller it implicitly knows you are referring to a view in the the app/views directory.

And you should improve your code slightly by not creating a local variable (for garbage collection purposes). So instead of:

```
var page = Alloy.createController('views/popup').getView();
page.show();
```

You should just do:

```
Alloy.createController('views/popup').getView().open();
```

You can find more info about this in a [splendid article by Fokke Zandbergen](http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/18/cleaning-up-alloy-controllers/).

/John